# Get amount of months from a date till today

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to count the months that has passed, since a specific date till today. For example, from januari till today (june) would be '5'

Keep it mind, it should work if its a year later, so the year has to be included.

Comment: use the unix timestamp. `mktime(time());`

Comment: you have to be more precise. How many months have passed from January 31st to February 8th?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use date_diff()

```
$df = date_diff(date_create('01/08/2012'),date_create('05/08/2012')); 

echo $df->format("Month: %M");
```

Comment: output (PHP 5.3.9): `Month: 00` - not what a European would expect

Comment: better use ISO dates, like `2012-01-08`